# Execute JavaScript after list edit mode is loaded

Tags: list-view, edit-form

I have a requirement to run some JavaScript once the edit mode of the list loads to assign some colors to the cells based on their content.

The JavaScript function which i am using has no errors but it does not make the changes on page as till then the edit mode is not loaded.

The same script runs fine on the normal view.

Comment: SP2010 or SP2013?

Comment: @JussiPalo 2013

Comment: You might want to share the code. Are you using `_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("myCustomFunctionName");`for example?

Comment: @yandr this seems quite helpful. Will confirm whether it solved my purpose or not after trying it out.

Comment: @yandr didn't solve my issue.